# Webapi2 returning ef object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem with entity framework object in a webapi project.
Since 2-3 days ago everything works fine, but now, the api I call always return "Out of memory exception".

Initially I check for the classic "circular reference error" but is not the case.

In the webapi configuration I have this

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

And to return ef object I use function like this

```
public Contatti GetContatto([FromUri]int id)
    {
        var db=new WebEntities();
        return(db.Contatti.Single(x=>x.IDContatto == id));
    }
```

There's a way to return an ef object (with its subobject) in a json response with webapi2?

Comment: What makes you think the "Out of memory" exception is caused by generating the json from EF6 objects? Did you check the memory usage on the server? Are you disposing large objects? When you restart the website, do you still get this exception?

Comment: OOM might have caused by other method(s). By the time you invoked GetContatto method, memory dedicated for the application pool was already exhausted, and it ends up throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really look at the code you've posted when I commented on your question, but now that I did I have some remarks:

**Always call dispose**, do not wait for the GC to clear memory. Though the "Out of Memory" exception may not be caused by this particular method, it is possible that you are also not disposing other (large) objects, like images. So review your code and dispose objects where possible. Best way to prevent "Out of memory" exceptions.

```
    public Contatti GetContatto([FromUri]int id)
    {
        using(var db = new WebEntities())
        {
            return(db.Contatti.Single(x => x.IDContatto == id));
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to return an ef object (with its subobject) in a json response with webapi2?

Yes, but I would really recommend not to return EF objects but **use DTO's** instead. Saves a lot of trouble!

To return an EF object, you'd better unproxy the object first:

```
    protected internal T UnProxyItem<T>(T proxyObject) where T : class
    {
        var proxyCreationEnabled = this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
        try
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return this.Entry(proxyObject).CurrentValues.ToObject() as T;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Always call dispose` Always is a strong word. We should not dispose DbContext inside each method, if we use Repository and Unit of Work Patterns.

Comment: to solve I used DTO, repository and unit of work pattern, so  everything is working fine. The question is only for my curiosity, because two days ago returniung ef object was working :)